# Copy & Paste is not working in my Kali Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: catalina, vmware

I am running VMWare Fusion 11.5 Pro on Mac OS X 10.15 Catalina

Copy & Paste is not working in my Kali Linux and my host (Mac OS X)

I checked the settings I see this

[image]

I search around, people suggest to install VMWare Tools.

I went to the menu the option is not lid up .

[image]

I am hitting the dead end.

What else should I check ?

Comment: Virtualbox has a really great active discussion board for things like these. If no one else here knows the answer...

Answer (score 3):

It takes me 2 weeks to stuck in this annoying stage.

If someone else, also face this issue run these in your Kali

```
apt-get update
apt install -y --reinstall open-vm-tools-desktop fuse
reboot
```

These 3 commands work for me.

## Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me a lot!